# How to perform database operations on browser close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser

I am developing online chatting in my website.
Some users close the browser when they are in online.
I want to done some database operations when user closes the browser

I use this one

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            if ((event.clientX < 0) || (event.clientY < 0) || event.clientY < -80) { 
}
```

it does not work in non IE browsers..........

Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event) question on how to capture the browser close event.

Now what you can do is do an AJAX call in the event to call a Web Service, which in-turn does update your database accordingly.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743119/preventing-web-browser-from-closing-until-ajax-response-is-returned) question to prevent browser being closed while you are in middle of an AJAX request.