# Send data to php on window close

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can you tell me why this doesn't work..?? also tried with window.unload but it also didn't worked

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
                 $.ajax({
             url:'logout.php',
             type:'POST',
             data:{user:$("#user").val()},
             success: function(response){

                   alert(response);
                 }


             })      

}
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743119/preventing-web-browser-from-closing-until-ajax-response-is-returned

Comment: Correct it is duplicate question but for answer you should use `async: false`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can set `async: false` on your AJAX call to make the browser wait for the request to finish before doing anything else, but note that this will 'hang' the browser for the duration of the request.

`async: false,`

Answer (score 0):

Make the ajax call `synchronous`. As the call is asynchronous, before you get anything back the window is closed.